# (Unity3D) Getting a grid-system to detect GameObject that is bigger than one tile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tile

I have run into this issue where I have a GameObject, for example size 1x3 - and the gameobject is only recognized for being on a tile because it's placed there and given coordinates in the inspector (for example 5 x, 0 y, 6 z). The problem being that the code only detects that there is a GameObject on one tile, the middle tile of the grid code.

I need to make sure the other tiles the GameObject is covering is aware that there is a GameObject there, so I can set them all to for example that they're not walkable on - or that you can use them as cover by being next to them. But so far the code only registers 1 tile of the GameObject - therein lies the problem.

Thing is, I don't know where to start. I have some ideas, maybe do a loop to check tiles next to them if there is a gameobject but then the code won't know if something is on that tile and the loop would also be quite heavy on performance - unless I do that loop on Awake or Start or something similar.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there some built-in thing in Unity that can detect if something is above the specific tile I created?

It's an own gridsystem for the record to support 3D, so I'm not using the built-in tilemaps system for 2D games that Unity offers these days.

Unity Version 2017.3

Down below is Gridbase.cs - this handles the world and spawns all nodes (tiles)

```
public class GridBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Grid Scale
    public int sizeX = 32;
    //amount of floors/levels, Y is up
    public int sizeY = 3;
    public int sizeZ = 32;
    public float scaleXZ = 1;
    // character scale
    public float scaleY = 2.3f;

    public Node[,,] grid;
    public List<YLevels> yLevels = new List<YLevels>();

    public bool debugNode = true;
    public Material debugMaterial;
    GameObject debugNodeObj;

    void Start()
    {
        InitPhase();
    }

    public void InitPhase()
    {
        if (debugNode)
            debugNodeObj = WorldNode();

        //debug check all values for the grid.
        Check();

        //Spawn Grid Function
        CreateGrid();

        GameManager.singleton.Init();


    }

    void Check()
    {
        if(sizeX == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Size x is 0, assigning min");
            sizeX = 16;
        }
        if(sizeY == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Size y is 0, assigning min");
            sizeY = 1;
        }

        if (sizeZ == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Size z is 0, assigning min");
            sizeX = 1;
        }

        if (scaleXZ == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("ScaleXZ is 0, assigning min");
            scaleXZ = 1;
        }

        if (scaleY == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("ScaleY is 0, assigning min");
            scaleY = 2;
        }
    }


    void CreateGrid()
    {
        grid = new Node[sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ];

        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
        {
            YLevels ylvl = new YLevels();
            ylvl.nodeParent = new GameObject();
            ylvl.nodeParent.name = "Level" + y.ToString();
            ylvl.y = y;
            yLevels.Add(ylvl);

            //Creating Collision for all nodes)
            CreateCollision(y);

            for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < sizeZ; z++)
                {
                    Node n = new Node();
                    n.x = x;
                    n.y = y;
                    n.z = z;

                    n.isWalkable = true;

                    if(debugNode)
                    {

                        Vector3 targetPosition = WorldCoordinatesFromNode(x, y, z);
                        GameObject go = Instantiate(debugNodeObj,
                            targetPosition,
                        Quaternion.identity ) as GameObject;

                        go.transform.parent = ylvl.nodeParent.transform;

                    }



                    grid[x, y, z] = n;


                }

            }
        }
    }

    void CreateCollision(int y)
    {
        YLevels lvl = yLevels[y];
        GameObject go = new GameObject();
        BoxCollider box = go.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        // Creates a box collider that has the whole size of the grid + a little bit more
        box.size = new Vector3(sizeX * scaleXZ + (scaleXZ * 2),
            0.2f,
            sizeZ * scaleXZ + (scaleXZ * 2));

        //Spawn box collider in center
        box.transform.position = new Vector3((sizeX * scaleXZ) * .5f - (scaleXZ * .5f),
            y * scaleY,
            (sizeZ * scaleXZ) * 0.5f - (scaleXZ * .5f));

        lvl.CollisionObj = go;
        lvl.CollisionObj.name = "lvl " + y + " collision";

    }

    public Node GetNode(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        x = Mathf.Clamp(x, 0, sizeX - 1);
        y = Mathf.Clamp(y, 0, sizeY - 1);
        z = Mathf.Clamp(z, 0, sizeZ - 1);
        return grid[x, y, z];
    }

    //get World Cordinates from any Node
    public Vector3 WorldCoordinatesFromNode(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        Vector3 r = Vector3.zero;
        r.x = x * scaleXZ;
        r.y = y * scaleY;
        r.z = z * scaleXZ;
        return r;
    }

    GameObject WorldNode()
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject();
        GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
        Destroy(quad.GetComponent<Collider>());
        quad.transform.parent = go.transform;
        quad.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        quad.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90, 0, 0);
        quad.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.95f;
        quad.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = debugMaterial;
        return go;


    }

    public static GridBase singleton;
    private void Awake()
    {
        singleton = this;
    }
}


[System.Serializable]
public class YLevels
{
    public int y;
    public GameObject nodeParent;
    public GameObject CollisionObj;
}
```

And this is the Node.cs file

```
public class Node
{
    //Node's position in the grid
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    //Node's costs for pathfinding purposes
    public float hCost;
    public float gCost;

    public float fCost
    {
        get //the fCost is the gCost+hCost so we can get it directly this way
        {
            return gCost + hCost;
        }
    }

    public Node parentNode;
    public bool isWalkable = true;

    //Reference to the world object so we can have the world position of the node among other things
    public GameObject worldObject;

    //Types of nodes we can have, we will use this later on a case by case examples
    public NodeType nodeType;
    public enum NodeType
    {
        ground,
        air
    }
}
```

this is the GridBase code pastebin.com/gazu9jPR that spawns the nodes (tiles) and this is the node script that triggers whenever gridbase references to Node class - pastebin.com/jk25n6ee

Comment: show us the code for your own grid system

Comment: can't really help you solve this without seeing your implementation.

Comment: - this is the GridBase https://pastebin.com/gazu9jPR that spawns the nodes (tiles)

and this is the node script that triggers whenever gridbase references to Node class - https://pastebin.com/jk25n6ee

Answer (score 2):

You can use trigger colliders at the place the gameobjects will be created on. You'll need a seperate collider for each grid cell. Make the gameobject with the collider the child of the grid cell (I don't exactly know your hierarchy, so I'll just keep guessing). Then, when the collider detects the gameobject, let the corresponding cell know that it is occupied. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I'll take a closer look into that. Btw I updated my post with the code for both the gridbase and node system so you can see the hiearchy there.

Comment: This isn't an answer, I understand you don't have enough rep to post a comment, but at-least wait until there is enough information to provide a well thought out answer instead of guesses.

Comment: I think that this is actually a proper answer. OP didn't ask to fix some code, but how to design a solution to a specific problem. This answer addresses the issue. There is no guessing here.

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud A solution to a specific problem for a specifically designed grid system that we know nothing about.  The "answer" for a possible solution to a design you know nothing about is still a guess.

Comment: @basilePerrenoud  the grid system code and node code is in the main post, pastebin links.

Comment: @Eddge like my previous post (can't tag two users in same post) - the code is updated and posted on the mainpost. You can now have a clear view of how it acts. I mean CaptainCrazy had a good suggestion but how I exactly implement it is the answer I'm still looking for, but at least CaptainCrazy gave me a pointer to a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

All the tiles need to have colliders. Also the object you place on the grid needs to have a collider(tick as trigger) which is big enough to overlap with tiles' colliders. Then you can use that to check how many tiles are covered by that object. The way you can do this is by using [Collider.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html) which is of type [Bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html). Bounds object has a method called [Contains](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Contains.html) which you can pass in the tile's [center point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-center.html) and see if it's covered by the object.

Comment: Not sure you would want to pass in the center of a tile to see if that tile is contained within a bounds,  if he has a tile that is the size of 2.75 tiles, it wouldn't contain the center of the furthest tile but it would still be on top of that tile.

Comment: I don't exactly know how he is implementing this system, but center point is an example. He might wanna use Collider.ClosestPoint to decide if a tile is considered as covered or not. But the point here is to use Collider to do all this checking.

Comment: I think that would be a better alternative as well to using the center point, I just wanted to point out the edge case I could think of that your current answer wouldnt work with.

Comment: @BehnamRasooli Thanks for the suggestion, the mainpost has been updated with the code and I'll post the pastebin here as well for GridBase - pastebin.com/gazu9jPR - and Node (tile)  pastebin.com/jk25n6ee

Comment: Currently theorizing this through @BehnamRasooli - since all tiles needs to have colliders, then wouldn't your suggestion with say Collider.ClosestPoint just detect the tile next to it, instead of the object above it?

Comment: I'm just giving you a starting point here not the final solution, which is the Collider component is what you need to use to achieve what you are after. The rest is up to you how you wanna implement it. To give you a bit more information: Transform.position is just a point(vector3), but the collider on the other hand is a volume(Bounds). Since you're looking for volume-based detection, you need to use collider.